# Cakephp3 query model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here is my Product Model:

```
$this->table('products');
$this->belongsTo('OrderProducts', [
    'foreignKey' => 'order_product_id',
    'propertyName' => 'order_product',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->hasMany('RefundProducts', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
    'sort' => ['RefundProducts.created' => 'DESC'],
    'propertyName' => 'refund_products',
    'className' => 'RefundProducts'
]);
```

My query:

```
$result = $this->Products->find('all', [
    'contain' => [
        'RefundProducts' => [
            'PriceUnits',
            'conditions' => $refund_condition,
        ]
    ]
]);
```

but it get all product,
i want to get only product have RefundProducts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is job for **`matching()`** method, which will create INNER JOIN with `RefundProducts`, so you will get *only* `Products` that *have some* `RefundProducts`. Conditions in `contain` limit only fetched associations

```
 $result = $this->Products->find()
    ->contain(['RefundProducts' => function ($q) use ($refund_condition) {
        return $q->where($refund_condition);
    }])
    ->matching('RefundProducts')
    ->distinct(['Products.id']);
```

I'm not sure what `$refund_condition` should do. This example will get `Products` that have some `RefundProducts`, but will contain `RefundProducts` only if `$refund_condition` is satisfied (so `RefundProducts` can get back as empty). Alternatively, based on what you want to filter, you can do it this way

```
->contain(['RefundProducts'])
->matching('RefundProducts', function ($q) use ($refund_condition) {
    return $q->where($refund_condition);
})
```

Comment: select 
    product_type, refund_price_unit_id, sum(refund_price)
from
    (select 
        refund_price_unit_id refund_price_unit_id,
            (select 
                    product_type_id
                from
                    products
                where
                    id = a.product_id) product_type,
            refund_price
    from
        refund_products a) b
group by product_type , refund_price_unit_id;

i don't know how to query In Cakephp Model query

Comment: @Cao First, please read this guide: **[Query Builder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html)**. You can find there everything you need to create and further customize your queries.
After that, if you will be still having problems to make your queries work, you can post another question with your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cao Thế Cường, have you tried relational query like this:

```
$result = Products->find()->contain(['RefundProducts' => function ($q) {
   return $q
        ->select(['field1', 'field2'])
        ->where(['refunded_product' => true])]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `where` to check if a column of the related table (`RefundProducts` in this case) is used:

```
// in your query-object
$query->where(['Table.column IS NOT NULL']);
```